# Regex to match groups

Tags: c#, regex

```
main:
  lda #$5
  sta $2
  lda #$0
  sta $0  
  lda #$10    
  sta $1
```

I'm looking for a regex that will match a Group like this: ["lda", "#$", "5"]. I've tried looking at tutorials for hours and it's still so very confusing to me.

Here's what I have attempted so far:

```
^(?<label>.*?)\s*(?<sign>[#][$])\s*(?<num>\d)$
```

It seems to match up only lda #$5

This is all in Visual Studios 2012 C#

Comment: Could you clarify what you expect the results to be?

Comment: I want my results to be this:

Group x = "lda", "#$", "5"

Comment: Here's what I have attempted so far:

^(?<label>.*?)\s*(?<sign>[#][$])\s*(?<num>\d)$

In this text:
main:
lda #$5
sta $2 
lda #$0 
sta $0 
lda #$10  
sta $1
 
It seems to match up only lda #$5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
(\w+)\s+([^\d]+)(\d+)
```

above works for all the input you have provided.

Comment: Thanks this is working nicely for me. I have another request. Here is the text:

http://regex101.com/r/yA0eX9

I want to match with everything except newlines and the "main:". So "nota" would become ["nota", "", ""] and "lda #$5" would become ["lda", "#$", "5"].

Comment: This should work :
    (\w+)\s+([^\d]+)(\d+)|(\w+)(\n)(\n)
http://regex101.com/r/dR9nX1

Answer (score 0):

`(\w+)\s+((#\$)(\d+)|\$\d+)` should do it: http://regex101.com/r/pJ0yH8

Comment: I also want to match for stuff like sta $5, how can I tweak it for that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex:

```
(?<=^\s*)(\w+)\s(\D+)(\d)
```

The code would be like:

```
String input = "  lda #$5";
String pattern = @"(?<=^\s*)(\w+)\s(\D+)(\d+)$";

Match m = Regex.Match(input, pattern, RegexOptions.Multiline);

if (m.Groups.Count == 4) 
{
    string firstpart = m.Groups[1].ToString();  // lda
    string secondpart = m.Groups[2].ToString();  // #$
    string thirdpart = m.Groups[3].ToString();  // 5
}
```